# Has anyone get issues with zoom module from swiper 6?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

The problem is that zoom module doesn't work at all. It not appears on html at all. I've done everything as in swiper documentation as you can see here:
https://swiper6.vercel.app/demos#zoom

Here it is my Swiper.tsx file:

```
const SwiperSlider: FunctionComponent<ISwiperSliderProps> = ({
  className,
  navigation,
  pagination,
  zoom,
  ...swiperProps
}) => {
  
  const swiperCoreModules = [
    ...[Autoplay],
    ...(navigation ? [Navigation] : []),
    ...(pagination ? [Pagination] : []),
    ...(zoom ? [Zoom] : []),
  ];

  SwiperCore.use(swiperCoreModules);

  return (
    <Swiper
      // navigation={navigation}
      className={classNames(className, styles.swiper, pagination ? styles.swiperPagination : "")}
      zoom={zoom}
      navigation={navigation}
      pagination={pagination}
      touchEventsTarget="wrapper"
      {...swiperProps}
    />
  );
};

export { SwiperSlide, SwiperSlider };
```

If I add a console.log with Zoom it shows as the other modules that I've added as you can see in the image:
[image]
And of course, zoom prop has true value on Swiper component.

And this is the scss file:

```
@import "~swiper/swiper.min.css";
@import "~swiper/components/navigation/navigation.min.css";
@import "~swiper/components/pagination/pagination.min.css";
@import "~swiper/components/zoom/zoom.min.css";
```

Note: All the other modules that I'm using are working, only this one doesn't work. And I've used it the same as the other ones.
Does anyone deal with this problem?